# bundle is installing a ruby directory in my project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I was trying to fix some garbage that was happening (frustratingly) by updating rubygems yesterday.  To fix spork, I typed "bundle install spork" before I realized I hadn't actually typed "gem install spork" and it installed everything in a spork directory within my project folder.  I removed that, and tried "bundle install ." which seemed to work.  But I just went to do a commit and noticed I now had a ruby directory in my project.

I removed that, but now don't know how to get bundle to go back to installing somewhere outside my project directory.  Does anyone know what command will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to use bundle install --system to get it to revert back to the default directory.

Answer (score 6):

If you ever accidentally invoke `bundle install foo` then it will try to install your gems inside a **foo** directory, and also will set this as your permanent choice in **.bundle**. So, take a look at **.bundle/config** and make sure there isn't anything unwanted in there.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install` with no path argument does it for me.